# Can a user set his public key without knowing its corresponding private key?

Tags: encryption, public-key, certificates, pki

I'm wondering if in public key infrastructure (PKI), a system user be able to set his public key without knowing its corresponding private key.

Can this be done?

Comment: Which implementation of PKI are you talking about? And more importantly: how does a user use their public key *without knowing* its corresponding private key?

Comment: In [Identity Based Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity-based_encryption), for many practical purposes a user's public key is their ID, e.g. their email, and is "set" before the corresponding private key is. The question is too imprecise to tell if that matches what's asked. What's the use case?